# Should I restore my backup or reinstall program's first?

Tags: backup, restore

If I want to make a new Ubuntu install just like my last one, should I restore from my backup first, then install all my programs, or vice versa?

The backup included the entire home folder and only that. Backup from deja dup (default Ubuntu backup software).

Comment: does not matters

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you put that in an answer, I'll accept it and close the question.

Comment: you are restoring what kind of backup, I mean from what kind of software ?

Comment: Sorry fixed. Deja dup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not matter. Because if you install and run the software after restoring back, the software will start using config files right away, because those files came from restore.

but when you install software and then restore the config files will be overwritten. You will be back when you made the backup. if you do this way, make sure you have closed all the GUI software and start them after restore of back so that the installed programs start with old config files and you get your system as you had expected

In either case make sure you reboot or at-least log-off and login immediately

*besides you did backup and restoration using deja-dup, if you had to face any problem it will warn you. You need not to worry about it*

Comment: It somewhat depends on how you restore. I'd suggest doing while logged in with another account. Otherwise it's difficult to close "all the GUI software", such as the desktop environment and window manager. Even if you log in via console, does .bash_history, etc. get overwritten on logging out?

Comment: @Sparhawk in case of desktop enviroment and window manager settings always takes place when you reboot or log-off you system, I dont think it would be a problem

Comment: Sorry, *what* takes place when you reboot or log-off? Saving settings? My concern is that if you modify DE/WM settings while they are running, they may get overwritten with the current settings.

Comment: Yeah, that's the other part of the question that was unclear to me. What exactly was backed up? I assumed the whole home folder, but perhaps not? DE and WM are definitely in the home folder, otherwise how would users have independent settings?

Comment: @Sparhawk alright I understand, but if user reboots immediately after backup it would not really mess up with DE,WM. so I have updated my answer. is it enough to keep away problems ? besides when you change DE,WM settings we do it while we use GUI right ? so what if the files are overwritten ? it may  change like the way we change settings using command line

Comment: I still don't think this answers it. What if DE/WM settings written to disk on log out? Then, you open up a new account with default settings, attempt to restore the previous settings, but the "on-screen" settings are still default. Finally, you log out, and the default "on-screen" settings are written to disk, overwriting the restored settings. Hence, I think the only way to restore safely is to do it when not logged in.

Comment: @Sparhawk do you know about Ubuntu's Backups software(also known as deja-dup) ? it backups home folder and retores home folder while you are logged in

Comment: I think Sparhawk may be right. When I restored, a bunch of errors popped up (as expected) so I rebooted. All my unity settings are back to what they were before the restore. I'll try restoring as another user and post a new answer if it works.

Comment: BY unity I mean you meant DE,WM settings right ? did you face any problem with your data or installed application ?

Comment: I mean wallpaper, launcher applications and behavior, etc. The only problems were with those. All the files were there and I didn't backup any applications.

Comment: @Prime624 this time how did you restored from other account or using same account in which you were logged in ? did your system got corrupt or unexpected behaviour you can fix ?

Comment: I have only restored once, from the same account. When I try from another account (in a few hours), I'll post details.

Comment: Alright. I tried restoring from a livecd, but I would have to pick a restoration location, and I don't know where that would be. Then I tried doing it from a guest account but I don't have the permissions. Then I tried creating a new admin account (called "temp") and restoring to original locations from there, but it restored it to the temp account instead of my main account. Does anyone know what I should put as the restore location?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19535/discussion-between-edward-torvalds-and-prime624).